# displaying ABUnknownPersonViewController with dismiss button

Tags: ios, objective-c

The Application I am working on has dialogs/UI entirely done by hand/code.

Presently it only has `Views/ViewControllers` and no `NavigationControllers` yet.
"Navigation" is done by displaying controllers on top of another, and/or hiding views.

I am trying to display a `ABUnknownPersonViewController`.

I manage to do it, but I cannot dismiss it; I tried to add a button but it did not even showed up. I am using the following code, but I do not see any dismiss/cancel in my `UIViewController`, how should I modify it ?

```
- (void)AddCallerToAdressBook
{
    ABUnknownPersonViewController *controller = [[ABUnknownPersonViewController alloc] init];


    controller.allowsAddingToAddressBook = YES;

    UINavigationController *newNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller  ];
    newNavigationController.title=@"AddCaller";
    UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                                                                       target:self action:@selector(dismissed)];
    [newNavigationController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:leftBarButton];


    [self presentModalViewController:newNavigationController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: try delegate methods of ABUnknownPersonViewController.

Comment: is the navigation bar shown ?